# How do you ignore all files but not subdirectories with Unison?

Tags: linux, regex, unison

I want to sync the content of all subdirectories of a given root but only a few files in the root itself. To do so I would like to ignore all files using the `ignore` directive (keeping all subdirectories) and re-adding the few files I want to keep with the `ignorenot` directive.
To do so I tried the following two things:

1. Adding a regex to exclude any entry in the root that contains a slash by adding `ignore = Regex ^(?!.*\/).*$` to my profile. But this results in an error message as follows with no further explanation:

   ```
   Malformed pattern "Regex ^(?!.*\/).*$"."
   ```
2. First ignoring everything with `ignore = Name ?*` and then re-adding every path that contains a slash with `ignorenot = Path */*`, which didn't work as expected since not ignoring directories doesn't work this way.

It seems to be a very simple issue, but I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it's not possible to do exactly what you want. When Unison syncs a file versus a directory, Unison can tell the difference between the two, but Unison doesn't refer to them differently (e.g. by prefixing a `/` to directories or something) in a way that allows a user to pattern-match against one or the other. For example, if you sync a directory named `deer` and a file named `phil` under the root `ROOT`, Unison sees them named as

```
new dir  ---->      ROOT/deer
new file ---->      ROOT/phil
```

You can't distinguish between `ROOT/deer` and `ROOT/phil`. Here are some suggestions though

1. Manually specify the directories you want synced by adding a line `path = deer` to your profile for each directory. I think this is the standard way to configure Unison anyways. Then for any files in your root directory you want synced too, say a file named `phil`, you can move `phil` into a directory that gets synced like `deer/synced-root-files/` and then add a [symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#POSIX_and_Unix-like_operating_systems) from that file back to your root directory

   ```
   cd ROOT; ln -s ROOT/deer/synced-root-files/phil
   ```
2. Invent a naming convention in your root directory that you can pattern match against. For example, name all and only the files you *don't* want to sync something like `ignore.phil`, and add a line to your Unison profile `ignore = Path ignore.*`.

Here's a link to the [**Path Specification** and **Ignoring Paths**](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#pathspec) sections of the Unison manual so future readers can easily find it.